# Sybase Database Error: Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object '' with unique index

Tags: sybase

I am trying to update a table but getting following error

```
update ReceivedFeed set feedTypeId=10 where feedTypeId in (3,4,5)
```

> Sybase Database Error: Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object
>   'ReceivedFeed' with unique index 'receivedFeedIdx'

giving unique index error. But i am only tryin to update records and not insert new.

Comment: What fields are included in receivedFeedIdx? It is possible the field or fields that are in unique index receivedFeedIdx might be getting duplicated since you are merging feed types 3, 4 and 5 into feed type 10.

Comment: the field which i am trying to update is only included in this index i.e. feedTypeId

Comment: Okay, so you have unique index called receivedFeedIdx on field feedTypeId. That means, each row much have a unique feed type id as long as feed type id is not null. If one row had feed type id of 3 and one row had feed type id of 5, your update statement will try to set the first row to 10 but will fail when second row is set to 10 because it will violate unique constraint.

Comment: But I am alreay having multiple entries for same feedTypeId in my db. there are 100 for 3 , 20 for 4 and 25 for 5.I just want to update these values to 10.

Comment: What happens when you do `update receivedfeed set feedtypeid = 10 where feedtypeid = 4`? If that works, try to update feedtypeid = 3. If that works, try feedtypeid = 10. That's likely to show you which feedtypeid's update statement failed.

Comment: *if you already have multiple feedtypeids etc..., i'm not sure having the unique index on the column is going to be super useful. consider removing it and simply having a normal index? theres not much point in having the unique index if they arent unique, and its bound to cause you issues later on with more complexe queries...
*also i'd rename your index. its a bit confusing. something like receivedFeedTypeIdx maybe?